# Renaming dataframe column elements using a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I want to restructure the Anscombe dataset from a 11 by 8 dataframe into a 44 by 3 dataframe, where in the latter the columns are an id parameter, the values for x and the values for y. In the final dataframe I want to rename the data elements so that "x1" <- 1, "x2" <- 2, etc. I am trying to do this with a for loop, but it's not working.

Can anyone explain to me why the for loop isn't working?

Also, is there a more efficient way to rename?

```
install.packages("datasets"); library(datasets)
anscombe_long <- melt(anscombe, 
             measured = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "y1", "y2", "y3", "y4")) #from wide to long

anscombe_x <- subset(anscombe_long, variable == c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4")) #separate x and y observations
anscombe_y <- subset(anscombe_long, variable == c("y1", "y2", "y3", "y4"))

Anscombe <- cbind(anscombe_x, anscombe_y$value) #combine into one dataframe

colnames(Anscombe) <- c("set", "x", "y") #change column names

for(x in Anscombe$set) {
  if(x == "x1") {
    x <- factor(1)
  } else if (x == "x2") {
   x <- factor(2)
  } else if (x == "x3") {
    x <- factor(3)
  } else {
   x <- factor(4)
  }
}
```

Comment: which melt do you use? `reshape2`?

Comment: use `ifelse` instead of `if` if you want to modify vector elements based on a condition

Comment: @RYoda, from the reshape package. I replaced the if with ifelse, but that doesn't work. Can you maybe show me your suggestion with some code provided?

Comment: No need to use `ifelse` since I have found a simpler transformation logic. But basically `ifelse` is a vectorized version of `if` with no need to loop. E. g. `Anscombe$set3 <- ifelse(as.character(Anscombe$set) == "x1", "1", as.character(Anscombe$set))` etc. for all your different cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop does not work because it iterates over each element of the vector and R does work "by value", not "by reference", this means, if you modify "x" R creates a new "memory slot" but does **NOT** modify the original vector.

Just remove the first character instead of looping over each row/element which is BTW bad practice - use a vectorized version instead that "loops" implicitly:

```
max.length <- max(nchar(as.character(Anscombe$set)))
Anscombe$set2 <- substr(Anscombe$set, 2, max.length) # remove first character
```

The result is a character type (I have not touched `set` so that you can see the difference):

```
> Anscombe
   set  x     y set2
1   x1 10  8.04    1
5   x1 11  8.33    1
9   x1 12 10.84    1
14  x2 13  8.74    2
18  x2  6  6.13    2
22  x2  5  4.74    2
23  x3 10  7.46    3
27  x3 11  7.81    3
31  x3 12  8.15    3
36  x4  8  7.71    4
40  x4  8  5.25    4
44  x4  8  6.89    4
```

PS: Also note the `Anscombe$set` is a factor type (not a string) which uses a numeric internally, see:

```
> str(Anscombe)
'data.frame':   12 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ set : Factor w/ 8 levels "x1","x2","x3",..: 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 ...
 $ x   : num  10 11 12 13 6 5 10 11 12 8 ...
 $ y   : num  8.04 8.33 10.84 8.74 6.13 ...
```

That's why I use convertion with `as.character` above...

Comment: Thank you R Yoda! This solution makes sense and works for me. Can you maybe explain why Looping over each row/element is bad practice in this case?

Comment: @SHW All basic data types in R are vectors and if you loop over each element of a vector and change it R copies the complete (!) vector into a new memory location just to modify one element. If you loop over all elements and modify each the complete vector is copied n times (n = size of vector). This is a performance nightmare. Therefore almost all functions work "vectorized", that is they loop internally and avoid copying the whole vector more than once. Rule of thump: Never loop over rows of `data.frame`, but looping over all columns is OK since you can apply a vectorized function then...

Comment: ok, thanks! As I understand correctly, this is an efficiency matter

Comment: @SHW In this concrete case the performance is no problem of course but the for loops make the code at least bigger than required and less elegant.